# Map a string array to a json object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a config-file:

```
{
  "permission": {
    "users": {
      "image": {
        "data": "example"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And an array with a called path like this:

```
path = ['users', 'image']
```

How can I get the data?

First try:

```
config.permission.path[0].path[1];
```

Second try:

```
switch (requestedPath[2]) {
    case 'users':
        switch (requestedPath[3]) {
            case 'image':
                mydata = config.permission.users["/image"]
        }
}
```

This will work, but is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to Get Object property using Array of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863576/javascript-how-to-get-object-property-using-array-of-string) and [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463) and [Access object child properties using a dot notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a bracket as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for the object, because you take a variable as key.

```
config.permission[path[0]][path[1]];
```

For a more dynamic approach, you could reduce the given data with a default object for not fiund properies.

```js
const getV = (object, path) => path.reduce((result, key) => (result || {})[key], object);

var config = { permission: { users: { image: { data: 'example' } } } },
    path = ['users', 'image'];

console.log(getV(config.permission, path));
```